# Constante caractère non valide

Tags: java, talend

I'm trying to do this:

```
 ope_tFilterRow_4.matches((row7.Subscription == null? false :
    row7.Subscription.compareTo('01-01-2014') > 0)
                       , "Subscription.compareTo('01-01-2014') > 0 failed");
```

And it said that:

> constante caractère non-valide error ( = Invalid character constant)!

In my table I have this same format of date and I have also tried to parse it and got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
row7.Subscription.compareTo('01-01-2014')
```

with

```
row7.Subscription.compareTo("01-01-2014")
```

EDIT :

I suppose that `row7.Subscription` is a date. Here is how to compare dates with Talend :

```
TalendDate.parseDate("dd-MM-yyyy","01-01-2014").compareTo(row7.Subscription)
```

Comment: i have donne it and it gives me that can't compare date with string

Comment: the same with no ' or " can't compare date type with int

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to convert string to dates in Talend. As you  seem to be french, here is a link which explains it in french : http://www.developpez.net/forums/d850781/logiciels/solutions-d-entreprise/business-intelligence/talend/developpement-jobs/comparaison-date-tfilterrow/

Comment: I believe you're correct. The main issues appear to be that Java strings always need to be enclosed in double quotes   and that comparison needs to be with compatible data types.